# How to send messages via PubSub and receive them in a future date

Tags: spring-boot, message-queue, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm starting to use PubSub in my spring boot project and I'm planning to implement a feature that I'm not sure if this is possible using PubSub.

Basically I need to publish a message to a topic and the subscriber does not need to receive the message immediately, the subscriber needs to receive the message say in 5 days (whatever date in the future).

I'm not sure if this is possible, I didn't find anything in the documentation. If this is not possible via Queue, I was thinking about having a table to keep the messages and have a cron to poll that table every day to see if the message will be ready to be processed by the Queue.

I'm just wondering if PubSub has a similar functionality to not process or deliver the messages to subscriber immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub does not have a way to specify that a message should be delivered at a particular time in the future. You might want to see if [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/) fit your use case.